# Radio Wiring diagrams and/or color codes?

Tags: electrical, nissan, audio, wiring

I've got an older Nissan truck (1994) that did NOT come with a factory radio.

A previous owner had an aftermarket style radio installed, and the installers used one of these universal radio installation kits.

When I took ownership, the last owner kept his radio.

I now have a factory radio out of a newer Nissan truck. It still fits into the opening, but it has a different connector than either the universal radio kit or the older Nissan stock style.

If someone has a color code chart that tells what color wires go where, I could really use this!

I need one of each to do this myself, otherwise I have to go have it installed professionally.

Again, I'm looking for a color code chart for:

- A Universal Radio Connector Wiring Kit, and
- A newer Nissan Radio Connector Wiring schematic

If it helps, my newer Nissan Radio comes out of a 2003 XTerra (non-Bose speaker version).

**EDIT:**

It looks like the wiring connector in my truck now uses browns and greens mostly for colors. The original owner did not keep his stereo after he removed it (sold it).

I've updated with the best picture I could get with my camera. It doesn't do well up close.

[image: Wiring Connector]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.wedophones.com/Manuals/Nissan/2003-Nissan-Xterra.pdf

That should help ;)

Not sure where you can find a universal wiring kit though. The aftermarket headunit should have a small diagram on it as well.

Comment: +1. Thanks! I've updated with a picture and extra info. Any idea how to tell who's connector that is in the pic above?

Answer (score 2):

this war radio wiring diagram will help you :
[image]

Comment: That is a good wiring diagram showing the industry standard colors. Now, we just need a way to map those colors to the non-standard colors used in older vehicles (like my 1994).

Answer (score 1):

Dude, I'll mark yours as the answer, but I found an AWESOME wiring schematic that got my truck's stereo installed last night:

[Install Doctor's Nissan Radio Wire Harnesses](http://www.jdmlegion.com/Assets/Nissan_Radio_Wiring.pdf)

Comment: Cheers! That definitely looks a bit more thorough! You can discern the connectors by the color of the wires leading into it. That's how I was able to wire up my car when I was completing my engine swap =D

Comment: The wiring connections on the truck were a different color and the wiring connections on the 2003 radio were also a different color. The plugs, however, matched perfectly and enabled me to snip the wires off of the stock-style connector one-by-one and solder them to the 2003 radio's connector. It took about 2 hours in my 90°F garage (thankfully, I did it at night), but it is **done**!

Answer (score 1):

This is the universal car radio ISO connector wiring. Hope it will helps :

[image]

Comment: The problem was a 1994 Nissan wiring on one side and a 2003 Nissan wiring on the other side. I'm not sure how this wiring diagram helps at all, but someone might get use out of it.